# Using Bootstrap with Rails 4. Why do I get empty space between <div> with each_slice( )?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Bootstrap with Rails 4. I'm creating two columns with each_slice(). However, with the following code, I get an empty big space on the left hand column.

```
<% @projects.each_slice(1) do |projects| %>
      <div class="col-md-6">
           <% projects.each do |project| %>
                <p><%= project.name %></p>
           <% end %>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

So to explain further, I get the following html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">This is displayed on the left</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">This is displayed on the right</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">This is displayed on the right</div>
    <!-- Here there is a huge empty space, between the first and fourth div -->
    <div class="col-md-6">This is displayed on the left</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">This is displayed on the right</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">This is displayed on the left</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">This is displayed on the right</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">This is displayed on the left</div>
</div>
```

The divs are of different length. How could I display them evenly, without getting a huge space sometimes between the divs? I have checked all the paddings and margins, and it's not because of them.

Comment: are they inline-block elements with text align:justify on the parent row?

Comment: The divs are just blocks and the parent .row from Bootstrap has only left and right margins.  No text-align:justify...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there's no "left" div between the 2nd and third divs.  `each_slice` groups an array into subarrays, but i don't see what the point of splitting them into groups of one element each is, which is what you're doing when you call `@projects.each_slice(1)`.  That could be simplified to

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p><%= project.name %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But, i don't think that's your problem.  What html do you actually want to generate, if what you listed isn't what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Max. That also works for displaying the two columns, however I still get an empty space between some divs. I would like there to be always equal space between all the divs. E.g. margin-top: 20px;

Comment: What do you mean by two columns?  How are you displaying these as two columns?  Can you put the html and relevant css on jsfiddle or something?  It's really hard to address this without knowing what styling you are doing to `.col-md-6`